# I only have 50 platinum in war frame

Tags: warframe

I've just started playing warfare and realised that I could scrap mods for more platinum. I really want to get a a rare skin that won't be on sale soon and I scrapped nearly all of my mods for the required platinum. But it says my amount of platinum hasn't increased despite the fact I should have earns another 60 platinum. Why is this?

Comment: I haven't touched Warframe in a while, but I don't think you disenchant mods into Platinum, but into something else. you can only trade for Platinum or buy it with real world money.

Comment: you just started playing. why the hell you want a rare skin? everything is rare for a newcomer.Everything is really cool in the beginning. people nowadays are so anxious.

Answer (score 4):

You might have mixed up Platinum and Endo, a new material added in to replace the old system of having mods designated as fusion cores that only had the purpose of powering up other mods.

Platinum can be acquired by

- Purchasing with real money
- Purchasing Prime Access
- Placing in the top 3 in a Warframe Contest
- Trading with other players
- As a rare drop from daily rewards

The wiki also list watching devstreams but the method it is distributed in this way is not specified.

If you want to make the most of platinum purchases you can wait to get a discount as a daily tribute. Discounts range from 25%-75%, but do not stack and can only be used for a single purchase.

> Source : http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Platinum and http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Endo